# Edit google apps scripts with IntelliJ-IDEA

Tags: ide, google-drive

> **TL;DR** I want IntelliJ to be able to import, edit, and export google apps scripts to and from my google drive seamlessly.

I have [Google Drive for Mac](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) installed, but opening gscripts there just shows me some of the file metadata like this:

[image]

I detailed some more information on my motivation for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062657/cant-import-code-from-google-apps-script-using-api).

I want to edit the scripts in my IDE because it has version control integration, awesome refactoring methods, and I'm more familiar with it than google's app script environment.

Is there an existing IDEA plugin for this? If not, are there any workarounds? I don't want to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the [Google Apps Script plugin](https://michaelsnowden.github.io/intellij-gas-plugin/) for IntelliJ IDEA by Michael Snowden.

You may miss the code hinting of the Apps Script editor but all the other perks you mentioned might make that worth it to you.

Comment: The plugin mentioned appears to have been removed entirely.  Source code is not available on GitHub and though there are cached pages and search results for it, for all intents and purposes this thing is **gone**.

Comment: Seems the plugin just moved for me: https://github.com/kehh/intellij-gas-plugin/

Comment: @Chtig that appears to be a mirror that someone (not the author) has put up, but yeah it should work all the same.

Answer (score 5):

There's also a git like tool called **[clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp)** by [Gratt](https://github.com/grant) for local development
You might find it at home if you use git

https://github.com/google/clasp